# If $X_n \rightarrow^{P} 0$ then for any $p >0$ $\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} \rightarrow_{P} 0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables
If $X_n \rightarrow^{P} 0$ then for any $p >0$
$$\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} \rightarrow_{P} 0$$ and $$E(\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p}) \rightarrow 0$$ .

## Proof

Let $\epsilon$ be given. Choose $N$ such that $$P(|X_n|>\epsilon^{\frac{1}{p}}) < \epsilon \> \forall n  \geq N $$
$$\implies P(|X_n|^{p}>\epsilon) < \epsilon \> \forall n  \geq N $$.
Note that $$\frac{|X_n|^{p}}{1+|X_n|^{p}}\leq |X_n|^{p}$$
So for all $n \geq N$
$$P(\frac{|X_n|^{p}}{1+|X_n|^{p}} > \epsilon) \leq P( |X_n|^p > \epsilon) < \epsilon$$
So $\frac{|X_n|^{p}}{1+|X_n|^{p}}\rightarrow_{P} 0$

I need help with the expectation part. I think I want to use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence but how do I show that $|X_n|$ is bounded

Comment: Apply the Markov inequality $E\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} \leq E\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} I_{|X_n|<\varepsilon} + E\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} I_{|X_n| \geq \varepsilon} $

Comment: You could also say that $\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p}$ is dominated by 1 and converges to 0 in probability. Then you can use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.